# Cocoapods installation error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoapods

I am facing below error on installing cocoapods in my project.

```
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
```

- `CocoaAsyncSocket (~> 7.4.1)` required by `Podfile`
- `CocoaAsyncSocket (<= 7.4.1)` required by `NHNetworkTime (1.6)`
- `CocoaAsyncSocket (~> 7.5.0)` required by `XMPPFramework/Core (3.7.0)`

So this is basically due to different version dependencies set in pod libraries.
So I have to install NHNetworkTime and XMPPFramework frameworks but they have  set restrictions in CocoaAsyncSocket versions as shown in above error.

Is there any way to fix such errors. Any help is appreciable.

Comment: Thanks Eric for your comment. Is there any way to change dependency in library ?

Comment: Okay Thanks for your suggestion. I will try to fork NHNetworkTime then change the CocoaAsyncSocket version.